# How to set the default tile size in Windows 8?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, live-tile

I have a Windows 8 Metro app and want to set the default tile size. I have set it to wide (310x150), but have forgotten how I did it. I want to change it back to square (150x150). How do you do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a wide tile is provided, the wide tile will be the default for the app at installation.  After the app is installed, the app cannot control the size of the tile.  The size of the tile is controllable by the user by selecting the tile (with mouse, right-click) and changing the setting ("Larger" or "Smaller").

Comment: Thanks. I wish you could provide a wide tile but set the default as square.

Comment: @msbg The user is in control of the tile size.  Why is it important to start with a square tile?  Concentrate on making great looking tiles in both sizes.

Comment: The live tile - I have a good small live tile, so I would prefer to start with it